# PLACEHOLDER - Sync markdown content from GitHub repo to answers in a Stack Overflow Teams community

Tags: app, placeholder, write-access

I think this Stack Apps post is required to gain write access to the API.

Answer (score 1):

The docs state:

> Apps must have a registered Stack Apps post to write. All content created via the API will have links pointing back to an app's Stack Apps post, to aid in giving an app's author feedback and in reporting abusive content.

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write

I'm hoping this is what they mean, and that this is that post.

Comment: Correct, but you don't need to post an answer per sé. The question itself is sufficient.